# Getting Sum of 3D Array elements by using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I need to Sum the 3D Array by using other function 'int ADD'. I want to pass the Array by using pointer and adding with pointer increase but I'm stuck at passing the Array. Here is my codes.

```
int(*pA)[COL][HIT] = A;   

printf("Sum Of Array A : %d",ADD((*pA)[COL][HIT]);

system("pause");
}

int ADD(int(*pA)[COL][HIT])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for ((*pA)[COL][HIT] = 0; (*pA)[COL][HIT] < 10 * 7 * 6; (*pA)[COL][HIT]++)
    {
        sum = sum + (*pA)[COL][HIT];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: If you have an array of X elements, what is the valid range of indexes? Now think that X is `COL` or `HIT`.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Information on what `A` is is missing.

Comment: Please explain your thinking behind `int(*pA)[COL][HIT] = A;` by explaining what you think it declares/defines/initialises. I propose to make a code comment with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what you need is something like the following shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N1  2
#define N2  3
#define N3  4

long long int add( int ( *a )[N2][N3], size_t n )
{
    long long int sum = 0;

    for ( int ( *p1 )[N2][N3] = a; p1 != a + n; ++p1 )
    {
        for ( int ( *p2 )[N3] = *p1; p2 != *p1 + N2; ++p2 )
        {
            for ( int *p3 = *p2; p3 != *p2 + N3; ++p3 ) sum += *p3;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N1][N2][N3] =
    {
            {
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
            },
            {
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
            }
    };

    printf("Sum Of Array a : %lld", add( a, N1 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Sum Of Array a : 60
```

Another approach is to reinterpret the 3D array as a 1D array. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N1  2
#define N2  3
#define N3  4

long long int add( int *a, size_t n )
{
    long long int sum = 0;

    for ( int *p = a; p != a + n; ++p )
    {
        sum += *p;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N1][N2][N3] =
    {
            {
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
            },
            {
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
            }
    };

    printf("Sum Of Array a : %lld", add( **a, N1 * N2 * N3 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But its hard to understand your second Code. add(int *a,size_n t) and add(**a,N1*N2*N3)  int *a and **a is not same type so I thought function would not work.. Can you explain your the second code??

Comment: @TaeHyeongKim The second function reinterprets a multi-dimensional array as a one-dimensional arrray.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names are confusing, since you are using a pointer to a 2D array (a pointer to a table) consider using `row` and `col` instead of `COL` and `HIT`

You need to pass both dimensions (rows and cols) to the function and also the number of tables.

Call the function using

```
ADD(tables, rows, cols, A);
```

And the prototype of the function should be something like

```
int ADD(int tables, int rows, int cols, int (*pA)[rows][cols])
```

Then, in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tables; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) 
        for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++) 
            sum = sum + pA[i][j][k];
```